# CSS not taking affect in jQuery Mobile after page navigation,

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a few simple jquery mobile pages set up. But when I navigate from one page to another, the extra CSS I added to the destination page doesnt take affect.

```js
jQuery("#home").click(function(){
jQuery.mobile.changePage( "/home.html", { transition: "slideup", changeHash: false });
});
```

I looked around and found this

```js
$('#form').trigger("reset");
```

But my page is mainly HTML right now so Im not sure how to reset all the elements in one go. Im pretty sure the transition is calling the problem.

Would anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, you don't need to hook up any `click event handler` for links to point to pages on any website, specially the ones using the `jQuery Mobile plugin`. It's even smart enough to detect a page containing multiple pages, or redirect to other pages.

Comment: Regular <a href> tags cause the same problem

Comment: what versions of jquery and jqm are you using? try this `$.mobile.changePage( "home.html", { transition: "slideup", changeHash: false, reloadPage: true });`.

Comment: Thanks but no joy. Im pretty sure its the transition causing the problem. When I remove it the CSS works fine.

Comment: where do you place the extra css?

Comment: Ive moved it from the top to the bottom and still nothing.

Comment: inside body? please be more specific.

Comment: Sorry, from header to below body.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37192/discussion-between-omar-and-daft)